# Throws "IndexError: tuple index out of range" when custom function in SQL query USED (psycopg2)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

In python script after establishing connection i'm running below code bit

```
import psycopg2
.
.
.
.
cursor = connection.cursor
cursor.execute("select  custom_fn(col_1, "xxx") as id from table;")
row = cursor.fecthall()
for s in row:
    print s
```

Here custom_fn is the custom function which takes two arguments 1) column 2) string (hardcoded).

Problem is whenever i'm running query like "select col_1 from table;" i get values but when i use custom sql function like  "custom_fn" it throws this error.
    "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

I have tried different ways, tried to lookup online different articles but still not able to find solution so any suggestions how it can solved would help. Thanks.

Comment: incorect indentation on `print`

Comment: @scharette Thanks for quick response, that mistake i made while typing here, I will correct it

Comment: If the string is hardcoded do you need to escape the quotes next to it?

Comment: did you try with triple quotes ? `"""select  custom_fn(col_1, "xxx") as id from table;"""`

Comment: The text literal should be in single-quotes: `cursor.execute("select  custom_fn(col_1, 'xxx') as id from table;")`

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your query in psql, so that it emits the columns you want
2. Use the same query with psycopg.

Without knowing what the function emits it is impossible to give you an answer.